# REST error and Mongo Id

Tags: mongodb, rest

I have a resource (example dogs) and have exposed the endpoint

/v1/dogs & /v1/dogs/{dogId}  -- GET

My dogs collection are in a mongodb and the dogIds are mongoIds(ObjectId).

if a request is sent for /v1/dogs/55243b709f6f672314103bb1 -- I get a 200 ok

if the same request is sent with an Id that is not mongoId ex (/v1/dogs/12342222)

Do I respond with Format exception or a 404 NotFound exception?

I am thinking 404. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO....Yes 404 or you can throw 400 Bad Request because the ID in your example would fail a validation check for length.  So it depends.  if you catch the error before you go to the DB, then its a 400 bad Request.  But if you take the request to the DB and do a lookup but come up empty, then its a 404 not Found.

Answer (score 0):

The request is valid - as it fits the schema (`/v1/dogs/<<_id>>`) - therefore it's **not** a Bad Request (`400 Bad Request`).

For that reason alone, I would send back a `404 Not Found`.

```php
$id = $strIdFromRequest;
try {
  $id = new MongoId($id);
} catch(\MongoException $objException) {
  //Send back a 404
}

//Query Mongo
//If nothing return, respond with a 404
$objCursor = $objMongo->findOne(array("_id" => $id));
```

Comment: I prefer to not hit up my DB if I do not have to.  Adding code that validates the request is pretty standard.  If you know the length or format of a particular request is wrong, then please do not waste any more resources processing it.  Hence there is a case for 400 bad Request.

Comment: You won't be hitting your database if the `id` is not valid. See http://php.net/manual/en/mongoid.construct.php

Comment: Nice, so even Mongo agrees that sending a specific response to imply validation error is worth doing.